# D3: change data based on svg element manipulation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag-and-drop

I'm new to [d3.js][1], so my question may be stupid.

I divided my svg into regions, and I appended circles for the user to drag around. Every region has an id, and every circle has the id of the region in which it was created.

What I need is to update the **DATUM** linked to the circle in the drop event. The other way around is quite easy, since when you change the data, the update() event does all the work. But is there a way for the svg element to change the data?

**EDIT**:

Some of the code. I edited so it is cleaner and more direct. The circles call the drag object and everything works, but the TODO section needs to be... hum... done:

```
var drag;
function configDrag () {
    drag = d3.behavior.drag();
    drag.on("dragstart", function() {
            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
        })
        .origin(function(d){
            return d;
        })
        .on("dragstart", draggrab)
        .on("drag", dragmove)
        .on("dragend", dragdrop);
}

function dragdrop(d){
    reg = regionOf(d.x, d.y);    // null if in undefined region
    if(reg){
        d3.select(this)
            .attr("cy", parseInt(reg.y1 + reg.y2) / 2);

        var regionId = getRegionId(d.x, d.y);
        // TODO update data.tsv with regionId
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, are you using `d3.behaviour.drag`? Can you post some code to show how your drop event works?

Comment: @CoolBlue Done. Thanks.

Comment: Well, there's a lot left to the imagination but I assume that data.tsv is the array bound to the elements being dragged, in which case d is an element of that array, so you just need to put the regionID on it. The new region can be inferred using d3.mouse which will give you the mouse position relative to the container element. All of that could be added as a method on your data.tsv elements.

Comment: Wow. As I said, it is a beginner's question. I used the _d_ argument without knowing the purpose of it. I've seen it on templates, and it worked,    more than the necessary for the time. Thank you for the explanation. Btw, it did it. If you want, post your comment as a answer for me to mark it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you bind data to a selection using `selection.data(values)`, `values` is always an array and normally an array of `object` elements. Those elements, or references to them, are bound to the DOM elements and can be retrieved using `selection.datum()`. They are also the `d` argument that is normally the first argument passed callbacks by the various d3 operator methods.  Because they are objects, when you change the value of their members, you are changing the values of the members of the associated element, in the original `values` array that was bound.